# How to make PDO queries in cakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I mean there must be a PDO Object initialized somewhere, and I want to use that instead of creating a parallel connection.

By request, here's the story behind it:
I'm making a registration form, which saves to two models, (Firms and Users) with a HABTM connection between them. CakePHP cannot work with HABTM in this form, so without ruining the model I had to do something like this:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Firm->create();
        if ($this->Firm->saveAll($this->request->data)) {

            for($i=0; $i<count($this->request->data['User']); $i++){ //működik :)
                $this->User->create(); // ?

                $a = $this->request->data['User'][$i];

                $b = randomString(28);
                $a['password'] = $b;
                $a['plain_password'] = $b;
                if($this->User->save($a)){
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The firm and a user have been saved.')); // no good
                }
            }

            //$this->Session->setFlash(__('The firm has been saved.'));
             return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The firm could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
```

I want to simply do a query, something like `INSERT INTO firms_users (user_id,firm_id) VALUES ($u,$f)`, because this is what the model can't do for me because of HABTM.

It would be great if this was done using a transaction, but I guess, using cakePHP standards, it's simply not possible.

Comment: Please add an example of what you're doing to the question - i.e. make it obvious why you want the connection object. Also indicate where you've already looked for it.

Comment: Why do you want direct access to the PDO object to do that (bad horsie!)? You can just use query, but the reasons you give for wanting to access the PDO object are basically false (the question to ask should be "how do the equivalent of this sql with CakePHP?" which is actually pretty simple - you make the join table a model and call save on it).

Comment: A join table as model? Seems exotic for me. Could you post an answer with my example code modified so it would create the join table rows, assuming that I have the FirmUser model?

Comment: It's [in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated). See the `What to do when HABTM becomes complicated?` section, your scenario is _not_ complicated - but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Accessing the Datasource**

You can access the model's data source using [Model::getDataSource()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_getDataSource).

See also: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html

**Running Manual Queries**

If you want to run a manual query without using Cake's built-in model query methods and relationships, you can do this:

```
$this->MyModel->query("INSERT INTO firms_users (user_id,firm_id) VALUES ($u, $f)");
```

Bear in mind the data here is not protected against SQL injection.

**Transactions**

I just saw your edit about wanting to run a transaction. Yes, you can do this with Cake. A model's datasource object has methods for this. You just need to begin the transaction on any one of the models which will be involved in your queries.

```
// Get the datasource
$datasource = $this->getDataSource();

// Start transaction
$datasource->begin();

// Rollback
$datasource->rollback();

// Commit
$datasource->commit();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/transactions.html

Comment: @RápliAndrás From the controller or model. In your controller, use `$this->NameOfYourModel->query()` or if you want to run a query in your model itself, just do `$this->query()`. The same applies for `getDataSource()` - they are both methods of the Model class.

Comment: I wonder what other isn't-possible claims can be slipped into this question =)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the PDO object for your database connection from anywhere. (Use 'default' DB profile or replace with a different DB profile.)

CakePHP 2 example:

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
$Connection  = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')
$PDO         = $Connection->getConnection();
```

CakePHP 3 example:

```
/** @var \Cake\Database\Connection $Connection */
$Connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
if (!$Connection->isConnected())
    $Connection->connect();

$PDO = $Connection->getDriver()->getConnection();

# To access PDO inside `Cake\ORM\Table` objects 
# you can use `$Connection = $this->getConnection();`
```